# Android - Status bar notification not showing

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

Am trying to show a notification in the status bar when my application do completes a process asper the business. I tried creating Notification. It executes but couldn't see in status bar. Couldn't get the error detail too. Below are the tries. But both didn't work.

```
private fun showNotification(title: String?, body: String?) {
    val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

    val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(body)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(soundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = context?.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: String) {
        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(requireContext())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        val notificationManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android 8 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel. This work for me:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.emo_no_paint_120)
        .setContentTitle("title")
        .setContentText("content")
        .setColor(Color.parseColor("#009add"))
        .setAutoCancel(true);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(
        NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}

notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

And you should add AppCompat library

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.0'
```

check this link

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels.html